# how do i simplify/condense the code (if possible)?

Tags: c, assembly

I'd like to present you my program in c and assembler code attached to his one. also, I've got some questions.

here is a piece of code in c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void podaj_znak(int tab[], int n);
int main()
{
    int tab[7] = {4, 5, 6, 2, -80, 0, 56};
    printf("Przed: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        printf("%d ", tab[i]);
    printf("\n");
    podaj_znak(tab, 7);
    printf("Po: %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", tab[0], tab[1], tab[2], tab[3], tab[4], tab[5], tab[6]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and asm right here

```
.686
.model flat
public _podaj_znak
.code
_podaj_znak PROC

push ebp
mov ebp, esp
mov edx, [ebp+8]
mov ecx, [ebp+12]
ptl:
mov eax, [edx]
cmp eax, 0
jl minus
ja plus
mov ebx, 0
mov [edx], ebx
jmp dalej
minus: mov ebx, -1
mov [edx], ebx
jmp dalej
plus: mov ebx, 1
mov [edx], ebx
jmp dalej

dalej: add edx, 4
sub ecx, 1
jnz ptl
pop ebp
ret
_podaj_znak ENDP
END
```

my question is, how can I simplify/condense the code?

edit: posting what the program does and what I like it to be like. it is just for me to train and to get used to assembler. the program is like you've got numbers from -inf to inf and it when the actual number is equal 0, it stays as it is, when it is something less than 0, it is replaced by -1, and when the number is more than 0, it is replaced by 1. the thing is, that I wanted to somehow optimize assembler code, but I don't know whether it is even possible to condense it.

Comment: Questions seeking to improve working code generally belong on [codereview.se], provided you adhere to their content guidelines.

Comment: I would replace the second `printf()` with a loop like the first one. Other than that, I don't see much room for improvement in the C code.

Comment: What is the assembly function doing? Why isn't it written in C?

Comment: it is just for me to train and to get used to assembler. the program is like you've got numbers from -inf to inf and it when the actual number is equal 0, it stays as it is, when it is something less than 0, it is replaced by -1, and when the number is more than 0, it is replaced by 1. the thing is, that I wanted to somehow optimize assembler code, but I don't know whether it is even possible to condense it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to optimize a little bit the assembly by calling only one time the `mov [edx], ebx` as follow:

```
ptl:
mov eax, [edx]
cmp eax, 0
jl minus
ja plus
mov ebx, 0            ; only set to 0
jmp dalej
minus: mov ebx, -1    ; only set to -1
jmp dalej
plus: mov ebx, 1      ; only set to 1
jmp dalej

dalej: mov [edx], ebx ; update the array[edx]
add edx, 4
sub ecx, 1
jnz ptl
```

Comment: The `jmp dalej` in the `plus:` block is redundant: it's just jumping to the next instruction.  You can also move an immediate directly to memory, like `mov dword ptr [edx], -1`, so you get rid of the `mov [edx], ebx` entirely instead of just factoring it out.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a good fit for this forum, but still:

For the C code, I'd create a PrintTab function that accepts tab and count and prints the table.  Then invoke it both before and after the podaj_znak call.

For the asm code:

1. PLEASE add comments.  I know this is probably just a class project, but still, get in the habit.
2. Why move [edx] to eax instead of just cmp [edx],0?
3. If perf matters, perhaps skip prolog/epilog and use a 'fastcall' calling convention.
4. Why repeat "mov [edx], ebx" for each case?  Move it down to dalej.
5. As a 'trick' you might try checking for -1, but then handle the other 2 cases with setnz.

Comment: these are pretty good advices from you, thank you. but anyways, I've tried cmp [edx], 0 instead of mov eax, [edx] and then cmp eax, 0, but it gives me an error like A2070: invalid instruction operands.

Comment: @J.White: that's because neither operand implies a size, so you need `cmp dword ptr [edx], 0`.

Comment: `but then handle the other 2 cases with setnz.`: if you're going to branch, probably the easiest is to branch for positive, and handle the other two with `sar eax, 31` to broadcast the sign bit, producing either 0 or -1.

Answer (score 1):

nasm syntax, may need subtle fixing for other asm, my solution:

```
; converts values in tab into [-1, 0, 1] as sgn()
; arguments: two on stack(int tab[], int n)
; modified registers: esi, edi, eax, ebx
; "no branch" version (except loop itself)
_podaj_znak:
    mov   esi,[esp+4]   ; tab ptr
    mov   eax,[esp+8]   ; count
    xor   ebx,ebx
    lea   edi,[esi+eax*4] ; tab.end() ptr
sgn_loop:
    lodsd               ; eax = [ds:esi], esi += 4
    ; change eax to [-1, 0, 1] by sgn(eax)
    test  eax,eax
    setnz bl
    sar   eax,31
    or    eax,ebx
    ; overwrite original value with sgn() result
    cmp   esi,edi       ; test if end of tab was reached
    mov   [esi-4],eax
    jb    sgn_loop
    ret
```

And then for the curiosity googling Internet (just the loop part is different), 3 instructions version (my is 4):

```
    ...
; modifies also edx in this variant
sgn_loop:
    lodsd               ; eax = [ds:esi], esi += 4
    ; set edx to [-1, 0, 1] by sgn(eax)
    cdq
    cmp   edx,eax
    adc   edx,ebx
    ; overwrite original value with sgn() result
    cmp   esi,edi
    mov   [esi-4],edx
    jb    sgn_loop
    ret
```

Both variants are branch-less, so they should have superior performance to any branch variant (but I'm not going to profile it).

Comment: I like that CDQ, CMP trick to get CF set for use with SBB or ADC!  I tried to come up with something on my own before really grokking your answer, and ended up with the same test/setnz/sar/or as you.  If there was a `cmp imm8, r/m32` (operands reversed from normal, so CF would be set when comparing a negative with zero), we could use the common `SBB same,same` trick to broadcast the sign bit without needing an upper-bytes-zeroed register.

Comment: BTW, put the `cmp/jb` together so they can macro-fuse on modern Intel and AMD CPUs.  LODSD is more uops than separate mov / add instructions on pre-Haswell, but it's actually only 2 uops on Haswell+.  (LODSB/W is still 3 uops on HSW and later).  You could also loop by counting an index up towards zero, so you don't need a separate CMP instruction.  So `[esi + 4*ecx]` is your address, starting with ECX=-count.

Comment: @PeterCordes about macro-fuse: yeah, I'm like 2-3 generations behind in performance knowledge, funny how the things shuffle back and forth (cmp+jcc is so 086-like). Loop to zero? Like `jcxz`, is that fast? Interesting, I never got used to it (as usually that final dec+jcc in loop didn't cost \*that\* much, as the body of loop).

Comment: No, with `inc / jnz` counting up from a negative index, since that macro-fuses into a single increment-and-branch uop on Intel SnB-family (and is still smaller code-size than `inc / cmp / jne` in the loop on other CPUs which can only fuse compare/test with jcc).  JRCXZ/JECXZ is not fast.